# Execute managebean method from javascript onload event

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

How can I make an ajax request that updates a `<h:dataTable>` from javascript? I am currently loading the initial data using `@Postconstruct` but that is significantly delaying the initial page load.

I am thinking about using `onload` event of `<body>` HTML tag to fire the request and update the datatable.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In *theory* the following should do it.

```html
<h:body>
    <f:ajax event="load" listener="#{bean.onload}" />
</h:body>
```

with

```java
public void onload(AjaxBehaviourEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

However, this is not supported for some reason. I've ever posted an [issue report](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1781) about that.

The following works, but it's in essence a hack.

```html
<h:head>
    <title>JSF 2.0 onload hack</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('hidden:link').onclick();
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="hidden" style="display:none">
        <h:commandLink id="link">
            <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.onload}" />
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

If you happen to use PrimeFaces, then you can use its [`<p:remoteCommand>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml) with [`autoRun` set to `true`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/remoteCommand.html).

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:remoteCommand name="onload" action="#{bean.onload}" autoRun="true" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Or if you're using OmniFaces, then you can use its `<o:commandScript>`

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <o:commandScript name="onload" action="#{bean.onload}" />
        <h:outputScript target="body">onload()</h:outputScript>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The `<h:outputScript target="body">` renders the `<script>` in the end of the `<body>`. The upcoming OmniFaces 2.2 will remove this need by [new `autorun` attribute](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/commit/0d8b6a6c089495d444c3e4d374960e35d74bb622).

```html
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <o:commandScript name="onload" action="#{bean.onload}" autorun="true" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: theory it should work. doesn't work.But the hidden button work like charm

Comment: The primefaces thing did the trick, even for redirecting (just return the page you want from the action method)

Comment: @BalusC I cannot open the issue report hyperlink. Is that issue solved yet?

Answer (score 1):

in jsf2.0 you can use the f:ajax tag in almost any other jsf tag e.g

```
<h:selectOneRadio id="myComponent" value="#{someBean.inputMethod}">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{someBean.A}" itemLabel="A" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{someBean.B}" itemLabel="B" />
       <f:ajax event="click" action=#{someBean.someMethod} />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

In this example the someMethod is excuted in the javasript onClick event for the "myComponent" selectOneRadio

Not sure if this is what you are after ....

Comment: Thanks for that, I want the request to be made automatically after the page loads

Comment: Mayby the PreRenderViewEvent might work for your problem`<f:view
    .......>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{someBean.download}"/>
</f:view>`

Comment: But this is not asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using the Metadata-Functions, as I could not use @PostContruct (FacesMessages are enqueued and not displayed when thrown in postconstruct mehtod... [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113498/warning-facesmessages-have-been-enqueued-but-may-not-have-been-displayed/10114017) last comment)

```
<f:metadata>
<f:viewAction action="#{bean.initProducts}" />
</f:metadata>

<h:body>
<ui:composition template="/templates/commonTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">

        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:dataTable id="table"
                value="#{bean.getProducts}" var="product"

              <!-- Table Stuff-->
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>


    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I am very new to JSF so  ... 
I DO NOT know very much about JSF's lifecycle phases, but this solution worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't run during JavaScript onload event. This runs far before the webpage is sent from server to client. OP is explicitly asking to run a bean method during JavaScript onload event. OP is not asking to run a bean method before the JSF render response phase.