# JSF 2: sharing scope among specific users

Tags: jsf-2, icepush

i'm not sure if what i want is possible, but still...
i want to share a data among users, like done [here](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Easy+Ajax+Push).  however, unlike this example, which uses `ApplicationScope` to share the data, i want the data to be shared not among all users, but only for groups of users (something like private chat rooms, and not a public space as in that example).
currently i use `ViewScope` but in order to update the display of the participants, use the hack i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523717/1187088), but this solution isn't very stable, as it throws JS error occasionally.
is there any sort of reasonable solution for my problem?
cheers,
eRez

Answer (score 2):

Hold them in a `Map` in an application scoped bean where the map key is the group identifier.

E.g.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ChatManager {

    private Map<Group, Room> rooms;

    // ...
}
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class GroupChat {

    @ManagedProperty("#{chatManager.rooms[user.group]}")
    private Room room;

    // ...
}
```