# render a primefaces message if url params come

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have the next url: `http://host:port/page.xhtml?response=something`

I want render a p:message if response==something

I have the next code:

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.response == 'something'}">
            <h:outputText value="message" /> 
       </h:panelGroup>
```

this render a `<div>message</div>`

I want render a `<p:messages />  or <p:growl />` and its value "message" if response==something

please help me to code this, and something else:

- Do I need a bean managed to send value to p:messages or p:growl?
- Do I need to call p:messages or p:growl from a `<p:commandButton />`?
- I can't use `<h:body onload="callFunction()">` 'cause h:body is on
  template xhtml  `<ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>` and my view
  is on `<ui:composition ...  <ui:define name="content" >` in other
  xhtml, and h:body is common to several views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd really need to use [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) to add a message to the context. On an initial request, your best bet is a

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="response" value="#{bean.response}"/>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

with

```
private String response;

public void init() {
    if (response != null) { 
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, response, null));
    }
}
```

You can by the way also use a separate `<p:messages globalOnly="true">` or `<p:growl globalOnly="true">` to display *only* faces messages with a `null` client ID.

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for)

Comment: @BelusC it's call bean but doesn't show it! log : facesmessage(s) have been enqueued but may not have been displayed, did you see it sometime?

Comment: Did you really use `<f:event type="preRenderView">` as answered? This problem suggests that you actually used bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` which may indeed be too late.

Comment: thanks @BelusC! I forget put <p:growl globalOnly="true"> tag like you indicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113498/jsf-facesmessages-not-displayed-back-instead-enqueued

Comment: It should also display without a `globalOnly="true"`. Apparently you had a `for` specified in your original one even though you mentioned in your question just `<p:messages>` and `<p:growl>` which are perfectly sufficient.

Comment: I meant <p:growl tag or <p:messages, I don't put it on xhtml page and log  facesmessage(s) have been enqueued but may not have been displayed, and doesn't show it! a novice error!