# How to load images using ajax when page loads

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a JSF page on which i have 8 images like.

****For jquery viewer Only:
 Please donot confuse with the JSf syntax. Behind the scenes it's all converted to plain HTML. Like h:panelGrid convert into table element. p:graphicImage convert into img element.Actually i want to know the logic to load images using jQuery ajax. Like using jQuery i call the server, then get the images from database and when images load completely on the path, then i change the img src attribute to change the default image with the loaded one. 
When page loads the on the default path there is a default image like /resources/images/no-preview.jpg. So i want that when images loaded then i replace it with like /resources/images/Image1.jpg,  /resources/images/Image2.jpg and so on **.**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="5" width="10%" style="position: relative; top: 50px; "
             columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >

    <h:outputText value="*" />
    <h:outputText value="Map: " />
    <p:fileUpload id="cityMap" widgetVar="uploader" description="Image"
                  update="city" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.jpeg;"
                  auto="true" fileUploadListener="#{cityDetail.imageUpload}"
                  style="position: relative;"  >

    </p:fileUpload>

    <p:graphicImage id="city" value="#{cityDetail.imagePath}" width="80"
                    height="50" cache="false" style="position: relative;">

        <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{cityDetail.putImage}" />

    </p:graphicImage>

    <h:commandLink value="remove" title="Remove Picture"
                   style="color: #0d5b7f;text-decoration: underline;"
                   onclick="if (! confirm('Are you sure, you want to remove picture?') ) { return false;}; return true; ">

        <f:ajax event="click" render="city" listener="#{cityDetail.removeImage}"/>

    </h:commandLink>
    .....
    7 more images in same format

</h:panelGrid>
```

In the constructor i am suing something like this to get images from database

```
public class CountryPages_Detail {
    private String imagePath = "/resources/images/no-preview.jpg";
    String path = externalContext.getRealPath("/resources/images") + "/" ;
    public CountryPages_Detail() {
        ....
        String cityMapQuery = "SELECT citymap From city Where cityid='" + cityID + "'";
        String countryMapFileName = "countryMap_" + saarcCountryId;
        // 7 more queries in same format

         ArrayList countryMapQueryArray = addCredentialsToList(externalContext, countryMapQuery, countryMapFileName, response);
         //7 more

         ArrayList mainArray = new ArrayList();
         mainArray.add(countryMapQueryArray);
         ...
         ArrayList result = ConnectionUtil.showImagesFormDatabase(mainArray);
    } //end of constructor     
} //end of class CountryPages_Detail

public static ArrayList showImagesFormDatabase(ArrayList list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList fileCredentialsList = ((ArrayList) list.get(i));
        String query = fileCredentialsList.get(0).toString();
        sqlStatement = conn.createStatement();
        resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery(query);
        if (resultSet != null) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                imageBytes = resultSet.getBytes(1);
                setResponceForDatabaseImages(fileCredentialsList);
                imageName = createFile(fileCredentialsList, imageBytes);
                if (imageName != null) {
                    imageNameList.add(imageName);
                }
            } //end of while()
        } //end of if()
    } //end of for()

    return imageNameList;

} //end of showImagesFormDatabase()
```

As you can see i get images from database when page loads. Get the images bytes from database, then create imagefile on the path from that bytes. But i have 8 images. If any of the image size is large then i have to wait which is frustrating.

I want that when page loads, then instead of laoding images from database i use ajax. Means my rest of the page get loads and images get load from behind the scenes and when all images get load then the images shown in the p:graphicImage. While image is loading then the loading icon should be displaying in the p:grahicImage and when image loads completely then icon gone and image should be shown.

How can i do it?

Thanks

**Edit:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
 <ui:define name="content">
     <h:form id="faqAddUpdateForm" prependId="false">
         <h:panelGrid columns="5" width="10%" style="position: relative; top: 50px; "
             columnClasses="asteriskColumns, nameColumns" >
         ....
         </h:panelGrid>
     </h:form>

     <h:form id="hidden" style="display:none">
                <h:commandLink id="link">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{countryPages_Detail.loadImagesUsingAjax}" />
                </h:commandLink>
     </h:form>

     <script>
         window.onload = function() {
             document.getElementById('hidden:link').onclick();
          }
      </script>
 </ui:define>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the images, when document is ready. However, the `h:body` onload does not work (as reported in [BalusC's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523717/620338)).

The referenced answer will give you a way to get it working. You need to trigger a hidden `commandLink` that has an ajax listener attached. The listener should call the method that produces the images and the ajax call should update the component containing the images.

To partially update your page on an ajax call, use the `render` attribute of `f:ajax`:

```
<h:commandLink id="link">
   <f:ajax event="click" 
           render=":faqAddUpdateForm"
           listener="#{countryPages_Detail.loadImagesUsingAjax}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

`render=":faqAddUpdateForm"` will render the whole form. If that is too much, give your `panelGroup` that contains the images an id (e.g. "imageGroup") and use this id in the `render` attribute:

```
render=":faqAddUpdateForm:imageGroup"
```

Comment: I modified my question please see it. But i want to ask that now the page loads immediately. When page loads i have default image on all my p:graphicImage. But when my `loadImagesUsingAjax`  method get call and i have all the images on my path, then how can i update my all p:graphicImage to show the loaded pictures? Thanks ?

Comment: Is it necessary to put : before form name ?

Comment: Yes, because it is a different form. You have two forms. To update one from the other you need to use the absolute identifiert starting with the colon.

Comment: Thanks what i did, i put my h:panelGrid inside a div element. Like ` <div id="SaarcImage"> <h:panelGrid id="saarcImagesTable">..</h:panelGrid></div>` And then i used ` render=":faqAddUpdateForm:SaarcImage"`. But now the page is not showing. If  i use just `render=":faqAddUpdateForm`, then everything works fine. Why? Am i doing something wrong by putting in inside a div?

Comment: You cannot update pure html components like divs. Give the panelGrid an ID and update this instead.

Comment: ok thanks now it is working :). But what if i want to update the pure HTML element like div in my case? Why i can't update pure html elements ? Thanks

Comment: Because they are not part of the jsf component tree. Wrap your elements inside a jsf component, e.g. `h:panelGroup` (which in fact will be rendered as div or span).

Comment: :) HHmm you mean to say whenever i want div on my JSF page, i should use h:panelGroup? Depending on the requirement like if i want to update the div, then i should use h:panelGrid instead of div otherwise it's ok to use div.

Comment: It depends ;-). Yes, but its panelGroup and not panelGrid.