# How to fill a dropdown dependent on the values of another dropdown in a datatable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a `<t:dataTable>` with two `<h:selectOneMenu>` dropdowns in two columns. The second dropdown is populated depending on the value of the first dropdown.

```
<t:dataTable value="#{tablaConfigBean.tablaConfigList}" var="item">
    <t:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.tabla}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="SIN CORRESPONDENCIA" itemValue="SIN CORRESPONDENCIA"/> 
            <f:selectItems value="#{tablaConfigBean.tablasList}" var="tabla" itemLabel="#{tabla}"  itemValue="#{tabla}"/>
            <f:ajax listener="#{tablaConfigBean.rellenaCampos}" render="seleccionCampoCorrespondido"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </t:column>
    <t:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="seleccionCampoCorrespondido" value="#{item.columnaCorr}">
            <f:selectItems id="listaCampoCorrespondido" value="#{tablaConfigBean.camposList}" var="campo" itemValue="#{campo}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </t:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

Bean:

```
public void rellenaCampos (AjaxBehaviorEvent event) throws Exception {
    dataTable = (HtmlDataTable) event.getComponent().getParent().getParent();
    fila = (cCNtablaConfig) dataTable.getRowData();
    tablaParaCampos = fila.getTabla();      
    camposList = cDAOtablaConfig.rellenaCamposTabla(idSistema, sistema.desEsquema, tablaParaCampos, 3);
}
```

Although the first dropdown dosen't have any value, its `<f:selectItems>` is always loaded by default. If I choose one of those values, then the `<f:selectItems>` of the second dropdown populates. The problem appears when the both `<h:selectOneMenu>`s have to show a value preinitialized from the database. As I have written it, the second dropdown is not loaded with the corresponding value unless I choose manually the value on the first dropdown. Then, the expected value appears.

I have tried something like this: [Execute managebean method from javascript onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522702/call-jsf-2-0-managebean-method-from-javascript-onload-event), but I'm not able to make it work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because the list of the 2nd dropdown in the last column is been bound to **one and same** bean property and in no way dependent of the current row.

In this construct, your best bet would be passing the currently selected value of the 1st dropdown to the `<f:selectItems>` of the 2nd dropdown.

```
<t:dataTable value="#{tablaConfigBean.tablaConfigList}" var="item">
    <t:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.tabla}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="SIN CORRESPONDENCIA" itemValue="SIN CORRESPONDENCIA"/> 
            <f:selectItems value="#{tablaConfigBean.tablasList}" var="tabla" itemLabel="#{tabla}"  itemValue="#{tabla}"/>
            <f:ajax render="seleccionCampoCorrespondido"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </t:column>
    <t:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu id="seleccionCampoCorrespondido" value="#{item.columnaCorr}">
            <f:selectItems id="listaCampoCorrespondido" value="#{tablaConfigBean.getCamposList(item.tabla)}" var="campo" itemValue="#{campo}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </t:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

*(I removed the `<f:ajax listener>` from the 1st dropdown and I changed the `<f:selectItems value>` of the 2nd dropdown)*

And move the original ajax listener method's job to the getter behind `<f:selectItems>`.

```
private Map<Tabla, List<Campo>> tablaCampos = new HashMap<Tabla, List<Campo>>();

public List<Campo> getCamposList(Tabla tablaParaCampos) {
    List<Campo> campos = tableCampos.get(tablaParaCampos);

    if (campos == null) {
        campos = cDAOtablaConfig.rellenaCamposTabla(idSistema, sistema.desEsquema, tablaParaCampos, 3);
        tableCampos.put(table, campos);
    }

    return campos;
}
```

Note that lazy loading + cache is implemented here. Also note that you should make sure that the `equals()` and `hashCode()` of `Tabla` class are properly implemented.

Comment: Many thanks @Balus. I needed this [JSF 2.0 method invocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284236/jsf-2-0-method-invocation/3284328#3284328) but only if I specify the get function `<f:selectItems value="#{tablaConfigBean.getCamposList(item.tabla)}`, I could make it work. If I put `value="#{tablaConfigBean.camposList(item.tabla)}`, I get `javax.el.ELException: value="#{tablaConfigBean.camposList(item.tabla)}": Method not found`. Why this happens?

Comment: Which servlet container are you running?

Comment: I now see that you edited your comment and switched it the other way round. Using `#{tablaConfigBean.getCamposList(item.tabla)}` is definitely right, using `#{tablaConfigBean.camposList(item.tabla)}` not. But I now see that you actually got this from my answer. Sorry, this was wrong. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Ah, don't worry. And I'm sorry too, indeed, my first comment was wrong. Many thanks again!