# Execute method after page has been loaded

Tags: jsf

I want to call an JSF Action after the website has been fully loaded?

it tried something like

```
<h:body onload="#{service.getMessage()}">
```

but in this case the method is executed before the page is visible to the user

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSF is server side, `onload` is client side.  Your only option would be to have the `onload` fire off an ajax request.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523717/516433) for an example.