# PrimeFaces. Update DataTable after Rendering

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a DataTable and want to persist filters. I can save filter values and put them back by calling the datatable.
I put filter values back on rendering. Now i want the table to be filtered.

Yes, i want to call a service and to get all data from it
Then i want to filter the table with values staying in filter fields.

I can't find a solution to start the filtering after the table got rendered.
[Solution with overriding PrimeFaces methods](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27195) can't be used in my situation.

Update:I'm trying not to use additional js, if a problem could be solved with Java or xhtml

I'm using Primefaces 3.5

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you! :)

Comment: @BalusC We trying not to use additional js, if a problem could be solved with Java or xhtml.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem.
I wanted to put a few persisted Filters in my DT and filter it initialy.

After a few houres I came up with this:

`<p:remoteCommand name="onload" oncomplete="PF('ticketTable').filter()" autoRun="true"/>`

The `<p:remoteCommand>` triggers `PF("ticketTable').filter()` after the page is loaded/reloaded.

It uses the `onload` event of the `<h:body>`.

I found it here :
[Execute managebean method from javascript onload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522702/execute-managebean-method-from-javascript-onload-event)

By the way. I'm using PF 5.0, but the remoteCommand is also present in 3.5 according to the Documentation. So it should work in 3.5 too.

I hope I can help you.

Regards
FlyingSpaten

Answer (score 0):

you have to invoke it's client side filter() method

```
oncomplete="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').filter()"
```

or by using:

```
 oncomplete="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').clearFilters()"
```

Comment: Invoke **when** and **why**?

Comment: <p:commandButton value="Save"
                 actionListener="#{bean.save}"
                 update="@form"
                 oncomplete="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').filter()"/>
Or you can clear filters at all with :

<p:commandButton value="Save"
                 actionListener="#{bean.save}"
                 update="@form"
                 oncomplete="PF('dataTableWidgetVar').clearFilters()"/>