# How to call a bean method when page loads?

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I am wondering how should I call a bean method after page loading. I tried something like this but it did not actually work:

```
            <p:remoteCommand name="autoRun"
                             action="#{enbBean.getFakeEndListForTesting()}"
                             autoRun="true" update="enbTable"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, that should work. Any exceptions? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5523717/4074715) contains some alternative ways of achieving what you need. The most standard way should be the first suggestion, to use

```
<h:body>
    <f:ajax event="load" listener="#{bean.onload}" />
</h:body>
```

with this

```
public void onload(AjaxBehaviourEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PostConstruct annotation for this method.

Answer (score 0):

below link visit. as far as i know xhtml page loading event run !!!

[When to use f:viewAction / preRenderView versus PostConstruct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844526/when-to-use-prerenderview-versus-postconstruct)